# How can I use the column_name of a dataframe as a value on the rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this Framework, 2 columns (Blue and Red) and values (0,1)

```
**Blue   Red**
   0      1
   1      1
```

I wanna a Dataframe result as this, If the column Red has value=1, replace this 1 with the name_column Red

```
**Blue   Red**
   0    Red
 Blue   Red
```

I can do it this with "for" but, do you know another way to do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to multiply  `df` and an array of same shape:

```
df * np.broadcast_to(df.columns.values, df.shape)
```

```
   Blue  Red
0        Red
1  Blue  Red
```

Which makes you end up with strings in all cells.

---

Another solution is to use `where` for each column

```
df.apply(lambda s: s.where(s.eq(0), s.name))
```

Which makes you end up with mixed types.

---

As a general rule of thumb, it's good to have single-typed arrays for each column.

Comment: nice, `df * np.broadcast_to(np.where(df.eq(1), df.columns, df),df.shape)` also works if there are more complex conditions.

Answer (score 2):

using `apply` function is more efficient. I am using `astype(object)` so I can use the `replace` function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1], [1, 0]], columns=['**Blue', 'Red**'])

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(object).replace(1, x.name.replace("**", '')))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 1):

using `np.where`

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df.eq(1), df.columns, df), columns=df.columns)
```

print(df1)

```
   Blue  Red
0     0  Red
1  Blue  Red
```

Answer (score -2):

You can call this function , maybe it might helps you:

```
def func(val):
    if (val==1):
        return "red"
    else:
        return 'Blue'
val=int(input())
print(func(val))
```

Comment: Thank, but If I have 50 columns this dont work for me, using apply function is better. But I learned of you, Thanks :)